# Error: Cannot find module 'js-yaml' when running "bower install"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, bower, bower-install

I am walking through basic set up of an AngularJS application (Just getting started) and am currently trying to install Bower components for the application.

When I run `bower install` from the terminal, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'js-yaml'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Path\bower\node_modules\configstore\index.js:9:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
```

I haven’t specified `js-yaml` module anywhere in my scripts (as far as I am aware), so not sure where this dependency is coming from.

I have tried deleting the node_modules folder, clearing the npm cache, including `js-yaml` within the `package.json` file then re-running npm install, but I get the same error when running `bower install`

If it helps, my `bower.json` and `package.json` files are shown below:

**Bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "starter-node-angular",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "latest",
    "font-awesome": "latest",
    "animate.css": "latest",
    "angular": "latest",
    "angular-route": "latest"
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "starter-node-angular",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express" : "~4.5.1",
    "mongoose" : "~3.8.0",
    "body-parser" : "~1.4.2",
    "method-override" : "~2.0.2",
    "js-yaml" : "latest"
  }
}
```

I am using WebStorm 10.0.4 (empty project as the starting point).

Has anyone come across this or a similar issue and possible point me in the right direction on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Modify the `package.json` file to look like [this](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/13509216/) and then do `npm install`. When that finish, then do `bower install`

Comment: Hi Lucio, Thanks for the feedback. I will try out the solutions offered later today. In the meantime, could you explain what  "js-yaml" : "latest" is doing versus  "js-yaml" : "*" ? Just what to understand the difference.

Comment: I couldn't see anywhere on the npm documentation to use `latest` to get the latest version of a package, the `*` is used for that. Doing so might install the package hence solving your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `sudo npm install -g js-yaml` first should get you in the right direction.

Comment: This answer clicked it for me. I just closed Webstorm and run it again as admin. Worked fine post doing this.

Comment: note that along with running webstorm as Admin, I also included --save in the npm command to save the dependency to the package.json file.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that its not related to your application but bower is broken. Try reinstall it:

```
$ npm uninstall bower
```

And then reinstall it like this:

```
$ npm install -g bower
```

That solved it for me.

Comment: appears this error after install bower: npm ERR! code 1